# Matrix representation of generator of (projective) $Z_N\times Z_N$ subgroup of $PSU(N)$ in the fundamental representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups

It is known that the $Z_2\times Z_2$ subgroup of $PSU(2)=SO(3)$ is projective in the fundamental representation of $SU(2)$ with the matrix representation of generators as: 
\begin{eqnarray}
v=-i\sigma_z;\\
w=-i\sigma_x, 
\end{eqnarray}
where $\sigma_i$'s are Pauli matrix and the projectiveness is
\begin{eqnarray}
vw=-wv. 
\end{eqnarray}
My question is how to generalize it to $SU(N)$. In other words, how to find two generators $V$ and $W$ in the fundamental representation of $SU(N)$ such that
\begin{eqnarray}
VW=\exp\left(i\frac{2\pi}{N}\right)WV;\\
V^N\&W^N\in\text{Center of }SU(N). 
\end{eqnarray}